# How can I connect my own class?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, xtext

I'm working on a RCP application and I would like to do something during the opening of a file in the editor. For that, I wrote this:

```
public class MyFileEditorInput extends FileEditorInput {

    public MyFileEditorInput(IFile file) {
        super(file);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

This class extends of the `FileEditorInput` class but at the start of my application, It's `FileEditorInput` which is opening. How can I replace by my own method?

Comment: How is the file being opened?

Comment: Which editor type? Show what else you've done, such as extension point registrations, etc. Eclipse's plug-in architecture means you can't just implement interfaces, you have to "plug in" to the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor is being opened by Eclipse using one of the normal mechanisms (such as double clicking on the file or using 'Open With...') then `FileEditorInput` will always be used. You can't change this.

If you open the file using one of the `IDE` class

```
IEditorPart openEditor(IWorkbenchPage page, IEditorInput input, String editorId)

IEditorPart openEditor(IWorkbenchPage page, IEditorInput input, String editorId, boolean activate)
```

methods or the various `IWorkbenchPage` `openEditor` methods which take an `IEditorInput` then you can specify your editor input class.

Answer (score 0):

@ greg-449 : Do you have a tutorial to do this? I'm trying to create my own editor. I do this in my eclipse.platform.custom plugin, Is It the good way?
[Project Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ADq.png)